# Using VARRAYs to overlap time series data

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, user-defined-types

I have some data want to overlap, I do it like below. and there may be some more smarter methods, since the data is very big, please advise.

Here is my VArray:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NUMBER_VARRAY_5 AS VARRAY (5) OF NUMBER NOT NULL
```

Here is the original data (table TEST_1)

```
"DATE_A","TOTO3_A"
"01/01/2005","281.25"
"02/01/2005","-9999.00"
"03/01/2005","291.50"
"04/01/2005","310.50"
"05/01/2005","298.75"
"06/01/2005","300.75"
```

The table TEST_2 is the result of overlapping by date lag 1 day and fixed days (5 days)

```
"DATE_START","DATE_END","O3"
"01/01/2005","05/01/2005","<Collection>"
1      281.25
2      -9999
3      291.5
4      310.5
5      298.75
"02/01/2005","06/01/2005","<Collection>"
1      -9999
2      291.5
3      310.5
4      298.75
5      300.75
```

Here is my code to do this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST
IS
   NUMBER_VARRAY   NUMBER_VARRAY_5 := NUMBER_VARRAY_5 ();
   L_VALUE         NUMBER;
   MIN_DATE        DATE;
   MAX_DATE        DATE;

BEGIN
   SELECT MIN (DATE_A), MAX (DATE_A)
     INTO MIN_DATE, MAX_DATE
     FROM TEST_1;

   FOR CUR_R IN 0 .. (MAX_DATE - MIN_DATE - 4)       
   LOOP
      L_VALUE := 0;

      FOR I IN CUR_R .. (CUR_R + 4)
      LOOP
         L_VALUE := L_VALUE + 1;
         NUMBER_VARRAY.EXTEND;

         SELECT TOTO3_A
           INTO NUMBER_VARRAY (L_VALUE)
           FROM TEST_1
          WHERE DATE_A = MIN_DATE + I;
      END LOOP;

      INSERT INTO TEST_2 (DATE_START, DATE_END, O3)
           VALUES (MIN_DATE + CUR_R, (MIN_DATE + CUR_R + 4), NUMBER_VARRAY);

      COMMIT;

      NUMBER_VARRAY.DELETE ();
   END LOOP;
END TEST;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this in pure SQL using the COLLECT function:

```
with dt as ( select max(date_a)-4 as mx from TEST_1 )
   , dr as ( select date_a as date_start
                    , date_a + 4 as date_end 
            from TEST_1 
                 cross join dt
             where date_a <= dt.mx )
select dr.*
       , cast(collect(TEST_1.toto3_a) as NUMBER_VARRAY_5) as coll03
from TEST_1
      cross join dr
where TEST_1.date_a between dr.date_start and dr.date_end  
group by dr.date_start, dr.date_end
order by dr.date_start
/
```

---

> " there are some errors:ORA-22814: attribute or element value is larger than specified in type"

Hmmmm, try this piece of voodoo:

```
 cast(collect(cast(TEST_1.toto3_a as number)) as NUMBER_VARRAY_5)
```

Comment: Hi, there are some errors:ORA-22814: attribute or element value is larger than specified in type

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NUMBER_VARRAY_5 AS VARRAY (5) OF NUMBER NOT NULL;

Comment: it is right, thanks, and ORDER  BY 1 what it is "1" in here means?

Comment: It's just a way of saying "sort by the first column of the projection" without actually typing the column name. If this answer has been useful please upvote and/or accept it. Accepted answers improve the quality of StackOverflow as a resource for other Seekers